# What is the correct way to change the Value of multiple Styles?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, resourcedictionary

I am currently trying to implement a Dark Mode to my application. I have multiple `ResourceDictionaries`, one `Window` and multiple `UserControls`. In my MainWindow I've created a Command that is supposed to change the Design during runtime.

One of my ResourceDictionaries looks like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
 
   <Style x:Key="SecondaryBorder" TargetType="Border">
       <Style.Setters>
           <Setter Property="Background" Value="#272726"/>
       </Style.Setters>
   </Style>

   <Style x:Key="WindowTheme" TargetType="Window">
       <Style.Setters>
           <Setter Property="Background" Value="#3c3c3b"/>
       </Style.Setters>
   </Style>

   <Style x:Key="HeadlineReports" TargetType="TextBlock">
       <Style.Setters>
           <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
           <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>
           <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Rubik Light"/>
           <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
       </Style.Setters>
   </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Here I would like to change the following values: `#272726` → `#55ffff` and `#3c3c3b` → `#FFFFFF`.

At first, I thought that I could create a global value for each colour and simply change the value with code-behind, however, I now learned that you are not supposed to do that with `ResourceDictionaries`.

What would be the correct way to change the colour throughout the whole application?

Comment: Say I want dark, light and default.  I'd create a resource dictionary for each.  Use the same key for a named colour which has different values in each resource dictionary.
Merge whichever is currently applicable into application.current.resources.
Reference that colour as a dynamicresource wherever you need your colour switched out.

You can do a similar process for system colours rather than re templating everything. Google them.

Comment: When you merge a resource dictionary with the same key but different value then it'll replace that value in application.current.resources and everything using it as a dynamicresource will dynamically change. There's a bit of an overhead so if you can live with reloading everything then you could instead use staticresource. Which will pick up a value only as that piece of xaml is instantiated into an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a copy of the existing `ResourceDictionary` and edit the values in this copy.

When you want to switch theme, you then remove the existing resource dictionary and merge the new one. Something like this:

```
App.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();
App.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary()
{
    Source = new Uri("dark.xaml") 
});
```